# How to implement optional first argument (to reproduce slice() behavior)

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [How can the built-in range function take a single argument or three?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13366293/how-can-the-built-in-range-function-take-a-single-argument-or-three)

The Python documentation for [`slice()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#slice) lists the following method signatures:

> **slice**(*stop*)
> **slice**(start, stop[, step])

Here are a few examples of creating a slice object with different numbers of arguments:

```
>>> slice(8)
slice(None, 8, None)
>>> slice(4, 8)
slice(4, 8, None)
>>> slice(4, 8, 2)
slice(4, 8, 2)
```

Note that if you call `slice()` with a single argument, that argument is used as the `stop` attribute (second argument with the two or three argument signature).

Since function overloading does not exist in Python, the typical way to allow a variable number of arguments is to use `None` as a default value, for example one attempt to reproduce the above behavior would be the following:

```
class myslice(object):
    def __init__(self, start, stop=None, step=None):
        if stop is None and step is None:
            # only one argument was provided, so use first argument as self.stop
            self.start = None
            self.stop = start
        else:
            self.start = start
            self.stop = stop
        self.step = step

    def __repr__(self):
        return 'myslice({}, {}, {})'.format(self.start, self.stop, self.step)
```

However this assumes that `None` is not a value that could be provided for `stop`, note the following difference in behavior between my implementation and `slice()`:

```
>>> slice(1, None)
slice(1, None, None)
>>> myslice(1, None)
myslice(None, 1, None)
```

Is there some other value that I could use in place of `None` that would indicate that the parameter was definitely not provided?  Alternatively, is there a different way to implement this behavior other than default argument values?

**Edit:** By the way, in CPython, [`slice()` is implemented in C](http://hg.python.org/releasing/2.7.3/file/7bb96963d067/Objects/sliceobject.c#l191).

Comment: Not a duplicate, since `None` is not a valid argument to `range()` so my implementation would work okay with `range()` but not with `slice()`.

Comment: +1 for your answer to that question, but I still don't think that this question is a duplicate even if the answer happens to apply to both.  The OP of that question could decide to accept a different answer that suggests using `None` for default values, which wouldn't apply here.

Comment: Sure, but they didn't. It's the same conceptual underpinning, the same basic approaches to answering the question, and ultimately almost identical code.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are a few ways to deal with the default argument issue.  `None` is the most common, but when `None` is actually a reasonable value to pass in, you can create a `sentinel`:

```
sentinel = object()
def func(arg=sentinel):
    if arg is sentinel:
       arg = "default"
    do_code()
```

Here's a related [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13075096/748858) where there was some discussion about using `Ellipsis` as the sentinel as `...` is also a singleton.

---

An alternative way to do this would be to use `*args` and unpack:

```
def func(*args):
   if len(args) == 3:
       start,stop,step=args
   elif len(args) == 2:
       start,stop = args
       step = None
   elif len(args) == 1:
       stop, = args  #Need the comma here.  Could write `stop = args[0]` instead ...
       step = start = None
   else:
       raise TypeError("Wrong number of arguments!")
```