# How can non default arguments come before defaults in Python's range() function?

Tags: python, loops, range

Normally, if you have a function or method in Python and try to put non-default arguments before default arguments, it does not work.

```py
#this will not work
def fake_range(start = 0, stop, step = 1):
  while start < stop:
    yield start
    start += step
```

`for i in fake_range(10)` : SyntaxError: non-default argument follows default argument

But for some reason, the range function behaves as if there are non-default arguments before the defaults

`for i in range()` : TypeError: range expected 1 argument, got 0

`for i in range(10)` : 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9

`for i in range(5, 10)` : 5,6,7,8,9

What is going on under the hood here? How come range works when I do `range(stop)` or `range(start, stop)` but this does not work with regular functions and methods?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/13366293/293048

Comment: @PaulM. It's not because range isn't a "regular function".

Comment: @someguy thank you!